# Overlay classes not reverting after being set to visible with OnClick in links

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, overlay

I am building a website, however I have encountered a problem. The initial links used to switch an overlay class from invisible to visible work, however when I click on the links in the visible overlay they will not switch the class back again. The code that I have is here:

```
<div id="login-overlay" class="overlay-hidden">
    <div class="popup-box">
        <a href="#" onclick="change_Login_Overlay_Class()" style=" float:right; width:20px; height:20px;">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link buttons to change the overlay class to visible are here:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-link" onclick="change_Login_Overlay_Class()">Login</a>
```

The javascript function is:

```
function change_Login_Overlay_Class () {
if($("#login-overlay").hasClass("overlay_visible")){
    $("#login-overlay").removeClass("overlay-visible").addClass("overlay-hidden");
}
else{
    $("#login-overlay").removeClass("overlay-hidden").addClass("overlay-visible");
}
}
```

If it is any help I am using the Bootstrap framework aswell.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function change_Login_Overlay_Class () {
    if($("#login-overlay").hasClass("overlay-visible")){
        $("#login-overlay").removeClass("overlay-visible").addClass("overlay-hidden");
    }
    else{
        $("#login-overlay").removeClass("overlay-hidden").addClass("overlay-visible");
    }
}
```

[image]
You wrote your classes wrong!

Comment: Im sorry, this is not exactly helpful, or im not seeing something? Could you tell me wht you mean with I wrote my classes wrong?

Comment: You check for `overlay_visible` instead of `overlay-visible` class.

Comment: Always double-check for this kind of stuff, and don't forget to use console, to see errors/warnings and check live for DOM changes.